# Writing a c program that reads from stdin and prints to stdout with no built-in limit of the line's length

Tags: c

I am reading the book of Kenneth Reek's Pointers On C and stumbled upon the following question:

> Write a program that reads lines from the standard input. Each line is printed on
>   the standard output preceded by its line number. Try to write the program so that
>   it has no built-in limit on how long a line it can handle.

What I couldn't understand is how to accomplish this without using a buffer to store the input before passing it as output.

I have tried to used standard functions for io operations like `fgets` or `scanf` but all of them seem to need a destination variable to store the input before it can be passed to the `printf` function.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191347/discussion-on-question-by-vertigo4444-writing-a-c-program-that-reads-from-stdin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Taegyung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10953328/taegyung) points out, a simple method is:

```
int c;
int LineNumber = 1;
printf("%d ", LineNumber);
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
    if (c == '\n')
        ++LineNumber;
}
```

One problem is this is going to print a line number for the last “empty” line. If we want to avoid that, then we want to print a line number only if (a) we have just started a new line, and (b) there is another character in the file:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
…

int c;
int LineNumber = 0;
bool AtStartOfLine = true;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (AtStartOfLine)
        printf("%d ", ++LineNumber);
    putchar(c);
    AtStartOfLine = c == '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it showed me a few nice practices to make my code shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {    
    int ch;
    int line_number = 0;
    bool found_newline = true;  

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {       
        if (found_newline) 
            printf("%d ", ++line_number);
        putchar(ch);        
        found_newline = ch == '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

just posting it here for everyone who might see it in the future.